# How to convert spark mllib word2vec model to glove txt format?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, word-embedding, glove

I use Spark MLlib to train a domain specific word2vec model and I need to use it in glove word2vec format. 
How can I convert it to glove txt format?

Answer (score 0):

After trying a bit in SparkShell, I found below code works for me:

```
val vectors = model.getVectors
val writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))
vectors foreach ( entry => writer.write(entry._1 + " " +   entry._2.mkString(" ") + "\n") )
```